# How can I run my shell script once the device wakeup from suspend mode?

Tags: linux, shell

I am able to run script on startup in my board(Embedded device with Linux base).
Once the device enter into the standby mode,the application run from the script will be killed.
How can I invoke this script so that my application should run once it wake up from the standby mode.
I can't use pm-utils,because it'll not supported. Any other methods are there to invoke the script on resume?

Comment: how do you control your computer suspend/wakeup? pm-utils? or systemd? or acpid? they should provide hooks, you just write something there.

Comment: You could probably use udev for this. Just investigate what kinds of events are fired when the device wakes up from standby, and have your script run when one of these events occur.

Answer (score 0):

You could try run a watchdog like script, checking if the application is running in a loop and restarting it when needed. In standby the watchdog script will stop and on resume it will restart your application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a shell and basic coreutils (a.k.a. busybox) are available on the board. You could start your app from a shell script. If your app dies, the script waits a few seconds and restarts it. I also assume your board goes to standby immediately after the app has died. Thus, the restart will happen after waking up from standby.
This solution also assumes that `your_app` does not fork when started.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    your_app
    sleep 5  # wait 5s, hopefully returns once board is in standby
done
```

You should start this script at startup, instead of `your_app` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
 ps -eaf | grep your_app
 if [ $? -ne '0' ];then
  ./your_app
 fi
 sleep 5
done
```

Check the `exit code($?)`. If non-zero, restart your application.